Sitecore headless shows error "page not found"
Using standalone Sitecore 10.4 and Headless Rendering v22 in a non-Docker environment, I created a headless tenant and a headless site (https://jss.local) in the Content Editor. I opted for the Sitecore-first approach because I couldn't find a way to create a site under a tenant using the code-first workflow.


I've also updated .env file and some other config files (eg: jss-app.config and jss-app.deploysecret.config) and deployed config files

Headless service is working

However, after running command jss start:connected and browsing localhost:3000, I see page 404



Not sure if it was related but after revisiting every config file and sitecore item, I decided to try different combinations of add-ons during installation and deselected nextjs-styleguide and selected rest options and worked


